# Kinesis Data Stream update ShardCount on Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis

I have a Kinesis Data Stream done in Cloudformation and I want to change the number of shards of one Stream, can I do that in Cloudformation by changing the value of the `ShardCount` down from 3 to 1 shard? Will they be merged all together?

I can't find anything for Cloudformation but the CLI has `update-shard-count` which split/merge them so I was wondering if the same was happening for CloudFormation.

What is the best way of doing that? Should I do it via the CLI and then change the code from Cloudformation before redeploying it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing shard count via CloudFormation has the same effect as changing shard count via cli, because they call the same underlying API ([`UpdateShardCount`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateShardCount.html)). Since you are already using CloudFormation, just change it in CloudFormation directly.